# Execute terminal commands in Python in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to run a small script from Python. I have 2 files; one called "example.py" and the other is "script.py". I want the script.py to run the example.py 5 times.

Inside the example.py is

```
print("hello world")
```

Inside the script is

```
import subprocess
for i in range(0,5):
    subprocess.check_call(['python','example.py'])
```

every time I run it in VScode this is what the terminal shows.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>>
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...     subprocess.check_call(['python','example.py'])
...
```

I would like to know what those 3 dots mean and why it isn't printing out Hello World 5 times. When I run

```
subprocess.check_call(['python','example.py'])
```

on its own I get

```
>>> subprocess.check_call(['python','example.py'])
Hello World
0
```

Thank you.

Comment: hit enter again

Comment: @Macattack Well.... that did it, lol. Thank you.

Comment: The interactive interface is giving you the option to write a multi-line statement within your for loop, so, it doesn't execute the loop until you have a blank line (enter x2)

Comment: @Macattack 
Now Im getting
`>>> for i in range(0,5):
...     subprocess.check_call(['python','example.py'])
...
Hello World
0
Hello World
0
Hello World
0
Hello World
0
Hello World
0
>>>`
is there a way where it doesn't print 0 after every one? Also, do I always have to hit enter or is there around that? Thanks again.

Comment: @Taha that's the return value of the check_call function - i.e., it completed successfully. Try editing your example.py script to have a typo and it should return the error code. See the documentation for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

Also you can just save your VS code terminal commands to another .py file and call that from the command line

Comment: You probably want to run `script.py` as a script, instead of interactively. I'm not familiar with VSCode but I'm sure it has the option to do that. BTW I edited the title to better reflect the question, since it's about using VSCode.